# classmethod with different overloaded signature between instance and base class

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, class-method

I am trying to write a class with an additional constructing method that accepts extra values.  These extra values are expensive to compute, and are saved at the end of the program, so `.initialize()` effectively serves as an injection to avoid recomputing them again at subsequent runs of the program.

```
class TestClass:
    init_value: str

    secondary_value: int

    @overload
    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls: type["TestClass"], init_value: str, **kwargs) -> "TestClass":
        ...

    @overload
    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls: "TestClass", **kwargs) -> "TestClass":
        # The erased type of self "TestClass" is not a supertype of its class "Type[TestClass]
        ...

    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls: type["TestClass"] | "TestClass", init_value: str | None = None, **kwargs) -> "TestClass":
        if isinstance(cls, type):
            instance = cls(init_value=init_value) 
            # Argument "init_value" to "TestClass" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"
        else:
            instance = cls

        for extra_key, extra_value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(instance, extra_key, extra_value)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, init_value: str) -> None:
        self.init_value = init_value


instance1 = TestClass.initialize(init_value="test", secondary_value="test2")
instance2 = TestClass(init_value="test").initialize(secondary_value="test2")
            # Missing positional argument "init_value" in call to "initialize" of "TestClass" 
instance1.init_value
instance2.init_value
instance1.secondary_value
instance2.secondary_value
```

How can I make the above work so that `TestClass(init_value).initialize()` does not require init_value passed to `.initialize()` because it's already been declared in `__init__`, while `TestClass.initialize()` does?

In short, how can I define a classmethod with different typing depending on whether it's called on an instance or a class?

These extra values cannot be declared in `__init__`, because of complex internals of the class that would be too long to repeat here.

Comment: Could you provide a true [mre], including the module imports for `overload`. If it comes from the `typing` module, it is intended only to provide hints to static type analizers like mypy and definitely not to allow run time overloaded version of the same function...

Comment: Yes, overload is from typing. I don't mind getting rid of it if there's a proper way to do what I want, which is having classmethod with a different signature depending from where it's called.

Comment: Ough, wait. This question is not about typing, but about `classmethod` instead. Please try running the following code in repl: `class A:` `@classmethod` `def foo(cls): print(cls)` (one code block per line, with obvious indentation) and then try `A().foo()` and `A.foo()`. Note that neither of calls is passed instance as `cls`. So `mypy` is right, one of your overloads (on `cls: TestClass`) is impossible. This may look like working at runtime, because all your assignments are modifying class variables, not instance variables. Downvote mine

Comment: After a second sight to the question, I may have a solution. But after @SUTerliakov's comment I wonder whether you want to set instance of class variables (my current code would set instance vars...)

Comment: I'm trying to set instance variables, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct problems here:

- how to declare a method that can be called either on an instance or on the class object itself
- how to explain that hack to mypy

Let us begin with the easy part and forget about mypy for a while.

When a method is called on an instance object (meaning it is declared on the type of the object), Python knows that it is a method call and prepends the passed arguments with the object itself: it is the common usage for a method.

When a method is called on the class object (meaning it is declared on the object itself), Python sees it at a normal function call and simply forwards the passed arguments. For that reason if `foo` is a method of `Bar` class, and if `bar` is a `Bar` instance, the following snippets are strictly equivalent:

```
bar.foo(args...)
Bar.foo(bar, args...)
```

That means that for your `initialize` method to be callable from the class object or from an instance of it, it should be declared:

```
def initialize(init_value, **kwargs)-> "TestClass":
    if isinstance(init_value, str):    # handle a str from the class object
        instance = TestClass(init_value)
    elif not isinstance(init_value, TestClass): # reject any other call...
        raise TypeError("Argument of initialize must be str")
    else:                              # handle a call from an instance object
        instance = init_value

    for extra_key, extra_value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(instance, extra_key, extra_value)
    return instance
```

This code will work fine at run time.

---

Now for the mypy part...

Unfortunately, mypy goal is to help the Python programmers to provide consistent and easy to maintain code. For that, it provides a static type analyzer to make sure that the run time parameters are consistent with the declarations **and that multiple overload declarations are all consistent**. Here begins the hell for your requirement:

- to be callable from the class object, the method would require a classmethod overload
- to be callable from the instance object and still give access to that instance object, the final declaration shall not be a classmethod nor a staticmethod

Said differently, no way for overload declarations...

So the only way I found is to tell the truth: you have defined an attribute on `TestClass` which is a function that can receive as its first argument either a `TestClass` object when it is called as a method, or a string when it is called on the class object itself

```
...
def initialize(init_value: Union['TestClass', str], **kwargs)-> "TestClass"::
    if isinstance(init_value, str):
        instance = TestClass(init_value)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a descriptor to return two different methods based on where it is accessed from. Here is an implementation:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Optional, Type, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

# Generic-bound typevars
PI = ParamSpec('PI')  # Instance method params
RI = TypeVar('RI')  # Instance method return
PC = ParamSpec('PC')  # Class method params
RC = TypeVar('RC')  # Class method return


class dualmethod(Generic[PI, RI, PC, RC]):
    """Decorate a method to have a classmethod variant."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        fget: Callable[Concatenate[Any, PI], RI],
        cget: Optional[Callable[Concatenate[Any, PC], RC]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.fget = self.__wrapped__ = fget
        self.cget = cget

    def classmethod(
        self,
        cget: Union[Callable[Concatenate[Any, P], R], classmethod[Any, P, R]],
    ) -> dualmethod[PI, RI, P, R]:
        if isinstance(cget, classmethod):
            cget = cget.__func__
        return dualmethod(self.fget, cget)

    @overload
    def __get__(self, obj: None, cls: Type[T]) -> Callable[PC, RC]:
        ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, obj: T, cls: Type[T]) -> Callable[PI, RI]:
        ...

    def __get__(
        self, obj: Optional[T], cls: Type[T]
    ) -> Union[Callable[PI, RI], Callable[PC, RC]]:
        if obj is None:
            if self.cget is None:
                # No classmethod available so return an unbound method, although this
                # means our actual return type is `Callable[Concatenate[T, PI], RI]`.
                # Since we can't specify an overload based on self.cget, the only fix is
                # to split this class into two, the first for before the classmethod has
                # been supplied, and the second for after.
                # Before classmethod:
                #   __get__ -> Callable[PI, RI] | Callable[Concatenate[T, PI], RI]
                # With classmethod:
                #   __get__ => Callable[PI, RI] | Callable[PC, RC]
                return self.fget.__get__(obj, cls)
            return self.cget.__get__(cls, cls)  # Return classmethod
        return self.fget.__get__(obj, cls)  # Return instance method


class Host:
    @dualmethod
    def initialize(self, **kwargs) -> Host:
        return self

    @initialize.classmethod  # type: ignore[no-redef]
    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, init_var) -> Host:
        return cls()
```

When testing this, I found Mypy loses information on the type of `self`/`cls`, and seems to process the redefinition by ignoring it, so it doesn't recognise the classmethod at all. Pyright does not have these problems, so [I've filed a bug report](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/16554).